# Cannot delete file in my Google Drive...message 'one removed file is still accessible by collaborators in Google Drive'

Tags: web-applications, cloud

I'm trying to delete some files of an ex that I have in Google Drive.  When I try to delete I get a message 'one removed file is still accessible by collaborators in Google Drive'.  The files still remain very much visible in my Google Drive.  Why can I not delete these files from my Drive?